# Is there a way to customize the ruleset that comes together with the PMD plugin for IntelliJ 2016.2.4?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, pmd

I want to disable some of the rules in the default ruleset. Is there an easy way to do that? Also, what should I do to reuse this setting on another machine?

Thanks,

MYP

Answer (score 1):

From IntelliJ PMDPlugin documentation:

> The user can run pmd on a single or set of files/folders and see the results in intelliJ. To run the predefined rulesets, go to Tools -> PMD -> PreDefined menu. PMD supports custom ruleset file, to configure goto settings -> PMD and add the rule set files that are required.